# How to get mt character to attack

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a beat em up game and right now i got my character attacking. I have 3 attack animation so far and works just about. This is what i want, if the player presses the attack button then the character will attack and if the player keeps pressing the attack button it will continue with its attack sequence (Note: I do no want if the player holds down the key, has to be a key press).

The problem is if you keep mashing the attack button it attacks but the problem is it goes to the next attack animation as soon as the attack button is down and I don't want that. How can i make it go to the next attack animation once the current attack animation has completely finished instead of jumping to the next frame midway of it's current attack animation. So i want the character to finish its attack and if the player still keys in the attack key it will go to the next attack frame otherwise it will stop. This is what i have done so far

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        //Attack variables
        var Attacking:Boolean = false;
        var Punches:int = 0;
        var Punching:Boolean = false;

        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        }

        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            //Note: I need these listeners here
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp);

                //If A key is down
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    Attacking = true;
                    Punching = true;
                    Punches++;
                }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            //If player is not attacking
            if (Attacking == false)
            {
                Punching = false;
                Punches = 0;
            }   
            else if (Attacking == true)
            {

                if (Punching == true)
                {
                    gotoAndStop('Jab' + Punches);
                }
            }

        }


        function KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);

        }
    }
}
```

Also within the last frame of every attack animation i have put down

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();
MovieClip(parent).Attacking = false;
MovieClip(parent).Punches = 0;
```

Not sure if this method is the best way around it or should i create a extended class/arrays if so how will i do this

Comment: So if the user hits the button the animation starts and while running the user hits the button again and after that stops. What is your desired outcome? The animation starts after finishing or the animation stops and waits for new user input (equals stage block)?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
            if (Punching == true)
            {
                gotoAndStop('Jab' + Punches);
            }
```

To

```
            if (Punching && !Attacking)
            {
                gotoAndStop('Jab' + Punches);
            }
```

So basically, it will make sure that an animation isn't already playing before it (re)plays the animation.

Edit: Even though you are calling gotoAndStop while still on that frame, it will replay the animations of any children MovieClips.

Comment: @ Tobias Kun: Yh so while the animation is running the [layer keys in the attack button and the new animation starts after straight away after the current one stops.

Comment: It's not working. I want to make it like this, this is a tutorial but i want it for AS3 and without holding the attack key

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhf68zmi0ktmeqq/DD%20%282%29.zip